# How to loop through a result set and repeat the same thing until last level

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to get the last layer from a product category. The twist is, the category got sub category and the last layer only have parentId of it's intimidate sub category.So I am trying to get the subcategory and then use that subcategory id to do the same thing again until it reaches to the last category. The only way to identify the last category is the linetype. So I was thinking to use while loop, but I am all confused.

For example

```
Declare @x Varchar(200)
Set @x = 'H506563'

Select stockCode
FROM stock
Where ParentStockCode = @x
```

It returns set of stockCode which will be the ParentStockCode in the next iteration and then those each will again give set of stockCodes. So this process will continue until I reach into the last level where the lineType will be S.

Is there any way to do that. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks
Hope this will help to understand better

[image]

The Last level which has the Part numbers -

[image]

Comment: You want a "Recursive CTE" to do this in SQL. [see here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) If you could please share your table schema and some sample data, I'm certain someone on here can write that up very quickly.

Comment: Why you can't call it by lineType immediately ?  Please provide the schema for both tables (category and sub-category) and a sample.

Comment: Because if I call it by line type then it will show other parts from different category, because the line types defines whether it is a partnumber or a category. So if I filter by that it will show all the partnumbers from the database.

Comment: @Ovic we need the schema, and where to know which part is assigned to which category as we don't see this in the screenshots that you've provided.

Comment: @Ovic there must be a pattern to register LineType for each product. You can check for instance the last layer you've provided, check the previous rows and the next rows, see if you can catch the pattern so you can work your solution from there

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough sample data. So I was not able to check the query. Query should return only stockCode's with `LineType = 'S'`. You should provide more sample data (not pictures) to get better help

```
declare @x varchar(200) = 'H506563'

;with rcte as (
    select
        StockCode, ParentStockCodeNo, LineType
    from
        stock
    where
        ParentStockCodeNo = @x
    union all
    select
        b.StockCode, b.ParentStockCodeNo, b.LineType
    from
        rcte a
        join stock b on a.StockCode = b.ParentStockCodeNo
)

select StockCode
from rcte
where LineType = 'S'

option (maxrecursion 0)
```